# Check User Warnings

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have the following code file to issue user warnings to Discord server members:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
const { Kick_On_Warnings, Warnings_Until_Kick } = require('../../settings/configuration.js').BOT_SETTINGS
const { Kick_Channel_Logs } = require("../../settings/configuration").LOGGING;

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'warn',
        description: 'Warn a member on the server.',
        aliases: [],
    },
    execute: async(Client, message, args, base) => {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed({ color: Client.color })
            .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))

        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get(Kick_Channel_Logs)
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.member(args[0])
        if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`Sorry, you are missing permissions to execute this command!`))
        if (!member) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`No Mention? No WARN!`))
        if (member.id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('You can\'t warn yourself!'))
        if (member.user.bot) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('You can\'t warn a bot'))
        if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('You need to provide a warning to give to the member!'))

        const userWarns = Client.db.ensure(`${message.guild.id}.${member.id}.warnings`, [])

        let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ')
        userWarns.push({ user: member.id, mod: message.author.id, reason: reason })

        const warn = embed
            .setTitle(`Moderation System | Warning Category`)
            .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .addField('User', member.toString(), true)
            .addField('Moderator', message.author.toString(), true)
            .addField('Reason', reason)
            .addField('Warning History', userWarns.length ? userWarns.map((s, i) => `${i + 1}: ${s.reason}`) : 'None')

        message.channel.send(warn)
        Client.db.push(`${message.guild.id}.${member.id}.warnings`, { user: member.id, mod: message.author.id, reason: reason })

        if (Kick_On_Warnings && userWarns.length >= Warnings_Until_Kick && member.kickable) {
            Client.db.set(`${message.guild.id}.${member.id}.warnings`, [])
            const embed = new MessageEmbed({ color: Client.color })
                .setTitle("Administration System | Kick Category")
                .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor(`GREEN`)
                .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setDescription(`**Action:** Kick\n**User Kicked:** ${member.user.tag} - (${member.id})\n**Reason:** - Reaching this guilds strike limit!`)
                .setTimestamp();

            const embed2 = new MessageEmbed({ color: Client.color })
                .setTitle("Administration System | Kick Category")
                .setThumbnail(member.user.displayAvatarURL())
                .setColor(`GREEN`)
                .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))
                .setDescription(`You have been **KICKED** from ${message.guild.name}!\n\n**Staff Member**: ${message.author}\n**Reason:** Reaching this guilds strike limit!`)
                .setTimestamp();


            const sendEmbed = new MessageEmbed({ color: 'RED' })
                .setDescription(`Sorry, I can\'t dm ${member} their dms are locked!`)

            let send = await member.user.send(embed2).catch(() => {})

            member.kick(reason)
                .then(() => {
                    message.channel.send(embed);
                    if (channel) channel.send(embed)
                    if (!send) message.channel.send(sendEmbed)
                })
                .catch(() => {})
        }
    }
}
```

Once a warning is issued or removed, the moderation system shows the users details, and their warning history; specifically how many warnings they have, and what the warnings are.

In short, I'm trying to build a command just to get their existing warnings similar to what populates after a warning is issued/removed, can't find how I would do that without actually issuing or removing a warning.  I know that I can probably copy it out of this code file, but I cannot for the life of me see which part I would need to use.

Any assistance greatfully received.

D

Answer (score 0):

If code is written properly then the variable names and functions should speak for themselves, this is also what I did to figure out what the pieces of code are you need.

The first line I found should store all warnings a user currently has in a const variable. Reading further this const should hold an array which is given away by the fact that 2 lines after this the function `.push` is called on this const. This is the line I am speaking about:

`` const userWarns = Client.db.ensure(`${message.guild.id}.${member.id}.warnings`, []) ``

Knowing that this const holds the array with all warnings a user has all there is left to do is displaying it. How you do this is up to you. You can put it in a plain text message, the description of a embed or display it in a field like it is done in  the example. The line that is responsible for showing it in your code example is this line:

`` .addField('Warning History', userWarns.length ? userWarns.map((s, i) => `${i + 1}: ${s.reason}`) : 'None') ``

For actually sending the warning history using embeds or a plain text message you can use the [Discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview).

Answer (score 0):

Final code that I am using is as follows:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
const db = require(`quick.db`)
const ord = require('ordinal')

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'warnings',
        description: 'Checks warnings of a member.',
        aliases: [],
    },
    execute: async(Client, message, args, base) => {
        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))

        if (!message.member.hasPermission('')) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`Sorry, you are missing permissions to execute this command!`))
        if (!message.mentions.members.first()) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription(`No Mention? No WARN!`))
        if (message.mentions.members.first().id === message.author.id) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('You can\'t warn yourself!'))
        if (message.mentions.members.first().user.bot) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('You can\'t warn a bot'))

        let mem = message.mentions.members.first()
        const userWarns = Client.db.ensure(`${message.guild.id}.${mem.id}.warnings`, [])
        if (!userWarns.length) return message.channel.send(embed.setDescription('That user doesnt have any warnings'))

        const warn = new MessageEmbed({ color: Client.color })
            .setTitle(`Moderation System | Warning Category`)
            .addField('User', mem.toString(), true)
            .addField('Moderator', message.author.toString(), true)
            .addField('Warning History', userWarns.length ? userWarns.map((s, i) => `${i + 1}: ${s.reason}`) : 'None')
            .setFooter(`${message.guild.name} |  `, message.guild.iconURL({ dynamic: true }))

        db.set(`${message.guild.id}.${mem.id}.warnings`, userWarns)
        message.channel.send(warn)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).